# Lime for Corona SDK - Camera focus on layer

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, lime

Is there any solution for setting up focus on layer in Lime framework. 
I would like to use this on game called "keepie uppie" with scrolling background (camera).
When you hit the ball the entire frame together with a ball and tennis racket moves up.

The figure below shows how I would like to make it work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Camera from Lime. It basically creates a display group and moves everything relative to that. You can focus the camera on one of your game objects. The github repo includes an example of doing just that.

https://github.com/GrahamRanson/Camera