# How to get the camera to follow the object in Corona sdk?

Tags: android, lua, camera, coronasdk

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556105/lime-for-corona-sdk-camera-focus-on-layer) somewhat differently has been asked a few years ago. During this time links were outdated, so I ask you again.

When object moving on the playing field it moving is beyond the screen. How to get the camera to follow him?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a library called perspective.lua for Corona SDK. It is made for this kind of stuff. It is really great for any kind of games, that you need to move the screen.

You can download it by googling (try perspective lua or perspective.lua)
You can also search for documents for it or examples.

Comment: Oh, no problem :)